# Has anyone use USARSim/ROS successfully?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

USARSimRos is designed to provide a seamless interface between the USARSim framework  and ROS ([www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org)).
Please go through [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/usarsimros/)

**If anybody use this successfully please reply. I find some bugs here.**

***Thanks in advance***

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97351/has-anyone-use-usarsim/ros-successfully?/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-11-03

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really found a bug you should definitely open ticket for it: http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/tickets/?source=navbar. Btw, this is not a real question.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2013-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/8381/mercy/) on 2013-11-03**:
There are 0 open tickets.

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-11-07**:
BTW have you tried opening a ticket? I could not do it :/